# Listen to http port with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, port

Is there any way to make my website appear on another port (for example, 7080) using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. .htaccess is only accessed/parsed when some already-in-progress HTTP request is being handled by Apache. By definition, you must have already connected to Apache and issued a request before any .htaccess files are even opened.

If you want to change ports, you have to do it at the .conf level

Comment: Thanks! Any way to do that in cPanel?

Comment: probably, but I've never used cpanel.

Comment: Yeah, if you have access to httpd conf and are able to stop and restart apache its super easy but .htaaccess is only used for credentials afaik.

Comment: @BeenCoding2Long: no, .htaccess is not just for credentials, but it can't affect fundamental server configuration things, like defining a new vhost or changing binding ports.